# CSS visual regression - do I need to store screenshots in git repository?

Tags: html, css, continuous-integration, regression-testing, phantomcss

There is a technique to check if something visually not broken in HTML and CSS markup - [visual regression testing](https://css-tricks.com/visual-regression-testing-with-phantomcss/).

We do following steps:

1. Check everything is ok.
2. Create a test "reference" (creating *.png files).
3. Change something.
4. Run test and check what changed.

What is better practice - all these "references" should be stored localy or should be commited to repository after check if everything is OK?

First case more simple and suitable for single development. Second can be useful if I have team and person with QA role - he can check and create references.

Do you have some experience or thoughts about how this will be on practice?

Comment: interesting, but rather off-topic for SO, better on http://sqa.stackexchange.com or http://programmers.stackexchange.com, maybe with some editing to reduce subjectivity.

Comment: So, in sqa or programmers? Any other suggestions where better ask this question?

Comment: I'm voting to migrate this question to http://sqa.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/16472/css-visual-regression-do-i-need-to-store-screenshots-in-git-repository